# ngOnChanges is only called once but not on update array

Tags: angular

I have parent component with 2 child components.

Initially the parent passes down data load via ajax to the child components.

But when I send a request payload - via event trigger- from child1 to parent and parent is loading data to update child 2 then the child2.ngOnChanges method is never fired!

**PARENT**

```
 gradingKeyModel1: IGradingKeyModel;
  gradingKeys: any[];
  @Input() gradingKeyModel: IGradingKeyModel


  ngOnChanges(...args: any[])
  {
    let currentValue = args[0].gradingKeyModel.currentValue;

    this.gradingKeyModel1 = currentValue;
    this.gradingKeys = currentValue.gradingKeys; // does updates CHILD1 initially successfully !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1
  }

  gradingKeyUpdate(request: GradingKeyRequest) {
    this.testsService.getGradingKeyPairs(request).subscribe(gradings => {
      this.gradingKeys = gradings; // does NOT update CHILD1 input field at least the ngOnChanges method is never called.
    });
  }
```

**CHILD1**

```
  groupedGradingKeys: any[];
  @Input() gradingKeys: any[];

  ngOnChanges(...args: any[]) 
  {
    let gradingKeys = args[0].gradingKeys.currentValue;

    if (gradingKeys) {
      let query = // do stuff

      this.groupedGradingKeys = query;
    }
  }
```

Why is the ngOnChanges not called on using the update button, that means after it worked once initially??!!

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please explain?

Comment: What do you mean with 'another controller' ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: You don`t need for every problem a minimal, super complete and perfect understable solution , - best cloud hosted ... - What is wrong abouot asking, why is ngOnChanges not triggered twice? and btw. the existing questions about the same topic did not help! I put all code here so you can regard the problematic code!

Comment: I found out this is not a problem with ngOnChanges. It does not work either with @Input() decorator alone or with a setter to intercept the new data. The input property always gets changed ONCE, when the components are rendered the first time. Now I try this link: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: In that link I found out that setter/getter work only when the components are rendered, when that is true thats a fine alternative: http://mean.expert/2016/05/21/angular-2-component-communication/  using rxjs subscribing to a service!